# 1998 Oldsmobile Intrigue - Takes fuel super slow

Tags: fuel-tank, gasoline, oldsmobile, intrigue

I think someone tried to siphon my gas tank and now it fills super slow. Like ten minutes slow.

So what part might be damaged and would it be in the fuel tank itself or in the fuel tank neck?

Comment: Any check engine light? The likely cause is the EVAP vent solenoid is stuck closed and there is too much pressure in the tank.

Comment: My Jet Boat is like this and so is my 1965 Studebaker .The Stude became a slow filler and the Boat was always this way.For your modern car I would suspect the pipework that goes to the fuel vapour recovery system.

Answer (score 3):

**possible vent hose issue**

As you are filling your tank the displaced gasses in the tank need to go somewhere.  If you have a pinched vent hose it could fill slower or be difficult to fill.

Check the neck to the tank as well as the ventilation system to ensure there are no obstructions preventing the movement of gasses or liquids entering or exiting the system.